# Java applet write file to local computer error

Tags: java, security, file-io, applet

I created a JAVA applet which downloads a file from the internet to the memory, do some operations with it, and then writes to the disk. I know that i have to sign the applet and create policy files, i did that but that didn't work.

Here is the code:

```
public static ByteArrayOutputStream file_kikodolva = new ByteArrayOutputStream() {  ... data ...};
public void bt_save_click()
{

    FileOutputStream output = null;
    try {

    FileDialog fileDialog = new FileDialog(new Frame(), "Save", FileDialog.SAVE);
    fileDialog.setFilenameFilter(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.endsWith(".txt");
        }
    });        

    fileDialog.setFile(GlobalData.filename);
    fileDialog.setVisible(true);
   if (fileDialog.getFile() != null)
   {
        System.out.println("File: " + fileDialog.getDirectory() + fileDialog.getFile());
        String filename = fileDialog.getFile();
        output = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        output.write( GlobalData.file_kikodolva.toByteArray());
        output.close();
        System.out.println("File saved: "+ fileDialog.getDirectory() + fileDialog.getFile());
        lb_save.setText("Saved.");
        bt_save.enable(false);
   }else
   {
       lb_save.setText("User canceled.");
   }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("File write error");
        Logger.getLogger(Send.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    finally {
        try {
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Send.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }   

}
```

I also tried to use Jar Maker. Here is what i did:
NetBeans -> Ctrl + F11 -> create jar file
I used KeyMaker to create Signer jar file.

Do you have any suggestions how can i make this work?

Comment: Maybe you've created self signed certificate and you should add it to browser?

Comment: Has your plugin asked you whether you want to trust the autor of that code? If the applet is properly signed and the signature chain could be verified, this only proves *who* wrote the code, not that the person writing the code is *trustworthy.* So the applet *should* ask you.

Comment: gkuzmin: Yes, i created a self signed certificate. Should i buy one, to make this work?
MvG: The applet asks for permission.

Comment: 1) For every catch, call `Throwable.printStackTrace()` and copy/past the output. 2) There are 2 ways to allow a modern applet to write to the file-system.  One requires either digital signing or a properties file, the other involves using the JNLP API.